# Strongly Type BeginForm Lambda Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, html-helper

I have the following code and I'm receiving an intellisense error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' because it is not a delegate type".

This had worked in the past, but something has changed and I'm now getting these issues.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm<EmployersController>(c => c.CompanyDetails(null, null), FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "bcms-ajax-form" }))
{     
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking there is likely more code here that you aren't displaying that is actually causing your issue.

Comment: Remove `(null, null)`

Comment: Why are you using this approach ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Shyju, I can't remember initially why I had used this approach, but I remember it being necessary. I think I'm just going to try and use BeginForm([actionName], [ControllerName], [Method], [HtmlAttributes]).

Comment: Sure, Keep the HTML form simple with only HTML markup. In ASP.NET MVC6, you are going to see this.

Comment: There's definitely an issue I've got going on, but I think it's something to do with namespaces, references or a DLL. All of my HTML.TextBoxFor helpers are having the same issues...